# django не запускается проект (pycharm)

Tags: python, django, pycharm

При запуске в Pycharm  проекта выходит ошибка:

```
File "D:\DjangoProject\web_project_env\Scripts\python.exe", line 1

SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file 
    D:\DjangoProject\web_project_env\Scripts\python.exe on line 1, 
    but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

подскажите как можно исправить?

Comment: Что и как вы запускаете-то?

Comment: Кажется он использовал русский шрифт)

Comment: @KryTer_NexT неа

Comment: а где исправить то этот русский шрифт?

Answer (score 1):

В самой первой строке файла добавьте `# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-`.

Comment: в том то и дело что не получается таким образом ставил я # -- encoding: utf-8 --

Comment: Убедитесь, что кодировка файла соответствует UTF-8.